# Symfony: Getting basic routing to work

Tags: symfony, routes, vagrant

this maybe due to my stupidity, but I could really use a hint here.

I have not done much with php so far, been mostly working with javascript, and now trying to get a grasp on Symfony. I'm working with vagrant and the great scotch-box, so I installed Symfony on this vm and created a new app. I tried creating a route that just returns "Hello world!", but i can't get it to work.

The route defined in the DefaultController is working. I created a new controller via the console command

```
$ php bin/console generate:controller
```

and called it TestController. This is it:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     */
    public function testAction()
    {
        return new Response( "Hello World!" );
    }

}
```

When navigating to [scotch-box address]/my_project/web I get the default route, but [scotch-box address]/my_project/web/test gives me a 404.

Maybe it has to do with the configuration of the vm, but this is not my expertise, so any nudge in the right direction will be appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:** After I managed to destroy my vm yesterday, I set up a clean scotch-box and installed symfony's demo-app, which is running just fine. I also have setup a clean Symfony project and changed only the DefaultController's route to "/home":

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
           'base_dir' =>     realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

my routing.yml reads:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

As I understand it, Symfony's welcome page should now be reachable via [scotch-box address]/my_project/web/home, but it isn't. Instead I can still reach it via [scotch-box address]/my_project/web, while /home throws a 404 page.

Maybe I'm wearing the idiot hat here, but I could not find anything in the documentation that would shed a light on this.

Comment: What happends if you go to `/web/app_dev.php/test`?

Comment: Access is permitted: 'You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.'

Comment: This is because access to app_dev.php is allowed only from localhost. If you want to develop outside localhost you have to edit this file.

Comment: @kba: I understand that app_dev is not allowed, but I should be able to reach the routes through app.php anyway, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it's true but if you haven't properly configured URL rewriting in your web server, you have to use  `/web/app.php/test` instead of `/web/test`. Also be sure that you deleted production cache before.

Comment: @kba: You were right, thank you. I did not see the forest for the trees. I removed the check for localhost from app_dev.php and could access my routes. They did not work for app.php due to the caching, which I was not thinking about. If you want to create an answer from your comment I will mark it as correct.

Comment: That won't be necessary. I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that it's because your `routing.yml` file is incomplete. Check if you have this in `routing.yml`:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:   annotation
```

If not, add it. This will "plug in" the annotation routing of your `AppBundle` into the routing of the whole project.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that's all correct there.